# What is this connector called and how do I open it?

Tags: connector, wire

[image]

And how do I open it to put in a wire? And can I use stranded wire or should i crimp (it's so small ferrule connectors dont fit)

Comment: what is printed on the side of the connector?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell but it looks like you should be able to fit a small screwdriver at the top and push down to open it. I would use solid core wire if I didn't have any ferrules that fit.

Comment: This is correct - small flat screwdriver in the top slot.

Answer (score 0):

These are commonly called "euroblock" and they are found in an astonishing variety from many companies...one part, two part, screw driver, spring loaded. Phoenix is probably the king of euroblock connectors.